# Isolating Behaviour In BDDs

Tags: unit-testing, testing, integration-testing, bdd

Suppose I have a program that does three things in succession:

1. `Task 1`
2. `Task 2`
3. `Task 3`

Now suppose I want to write `BDDs` for Task 2. Let us say when it fails. Now `Task 2` is performed only after `Task 1` succeeds. But Task 1 itself can succeed in many ways (for instance, we my program retries `Task 1` if the downstream system responds with an error for a fixed number of times). My question is, what all behaviour of `Task 1` should I consider when writing tests for `Task 2`?

```
Given_Task2Fails_Task1IsRetried_Expect_SomeBehaviour

Given_Task2Fails_Task1IsNotRetried_Expect_SomeBehaviour
```

If this is the case, then I need create all the permutations and combinations of each of the tasks keeping Task 2 as constant. This blows up the number of scenarios with a large amount of duplicate code. This is what I mean:

```
Given_Task2Fails_Task1IsRetried_Task3IsNotRetried_Expect_SomeBehaviour

Given_Task2Fails_Task1IsNotRetried_Task3IsNotRetried_Expect_SomeBehaviour

Given_Task2Fails_Task1IsRetried_Task3IsRetried_Expect_SomeBehaviour

Given_Task2Fails_Task1IsNotRetried_Task3IsRetried_Expect_SomeBehaviour
```

How do I write solid scenarios in such cases? Ideally, I would want to vary each and every parameter of my system keeping `Task 2` constant. But that's like a brute-force approach and I am pretty sure there are better approaches out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assume Task 1 has succeeded when writing tests for Task 2. The various ways Task 1 can fail — and recover — is not something you need to capture in tests verifying the behavior of Task 2.

```
Given Task 1 succeeded
When Task 2 is performed
Then Outcome 2 should have happened
```

What happens when Task 1 fails is not even a concern for tests asserting that Task 1 succeeds. In fact, the various ways Task 1 can fail could be (and possibly *should* be) captured as their own scenarios, unit tests or integration tests.